# Proper use of 'the' in a sentense

Tags: word-usage

Is this correct to say:

> How to Remove the Comment Form from **the** Jetpack Carousel Screen

This is a title of a blog post. What concerns me is the second *the*. Jetpack and Carousel are the names of the plugin and a module within that plugin respectively.

Is it necessary to use it here or I can remove it?

Comment: The reference is to a specific and previously identified screen. The definite article is appropriate and necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If, instead of talking about this particular module's screen, you were just talking about your own computer screen, wouldn't you write

> How to remove the comment form from **the** screen

I would write it like that, therefore I would also keep the ***the*** in your sentence.